# Seek to loop stored data in output going sideways

Tags: jquery, xml

**att: this post have been updated below.**

This thread is last resort before I sit down to hardcode it all, which vex me because I suspect that it is actually fairly simple.. Bear with me..

I am trying to dynamically replicate(?) an object in such a manner that info is pulled from data source, one object is filled, and then do it with next data again and again until loop ends. I’m thinking that this is done inside a responsive grid, so when the objects have multiplied to fill a "row" and hits the wall it simply continues underneath.

```
image,
name,
description
```

*And again and again next to it >*

I cannot manage that.

---

After trying to solve this via various methods all I get is the down spiral until end of pulled data.

```
image,
name,
description

image,
name,
description
```

*And again and again below V*

Since I have been trying to solve this for some days now, the data is now available in various form. I have it in a mysql database as well as **XML** and json documents after trying many guides. I've been through a lot in the effort to figure this out :) "Idea" + "lets google how to do it" usually gets things done, but apparently not this time.

If anyone read this far and are willing to point in the right direction I would be sincerely grateful. The echo of how to solve this is probably equivalent in the various coding languages​​, but gladly a solution that is **jQuery** (Q is tagged jQuery+XML). The hunt for solution had me reading about lots of other nice things one can do with jQuery.

(I believe that answer to this issue is relevant to others on account that my hunt only have resulted in decade old guides regarding "adobe spry" and how to populate columns in tables with php and the such. The beautiful images I made describing the issue could not be posted, but I Hope my layman lingo is descriptive enough)

---

**update starts here**

All right. So last night I sat down with a coffe and watched the video tutorials over at try.jQuery.com, and that gave me a better idea about what things are named and the such to do improved research.

That lead me to this: [dynamically creating HTML divs with JS from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639791/dynamically-creating-html-divs-with-js-from-xml)
that had a comment that lead me to this: http://think2loud.com/224-reading-xml-with-jquery/

and yada yada yada,
sort of got it working now.

I am using Bootstrap, and managed to append a div with css class that line them up nice now and breaks against the wall and continues on row underneath. As desired.

Code looks like this, and please - no laughing.
http://jsfiddle.net/FkXa6/

Using "inspector" in browser the produced code seems about right. div is named after product artnr, class is bootstrappy, and it holds the thumbmail. The -artnr- in cleartext is not supposed to be in there, but can not get it out of there to be placed in a div below thumbnail. (so I left it for now as it shows up neatly below the thumbnail)

So, getting the -artnr- out of the first div so that I get three div's is what I would like help with. All trials seems to break the code, because every try = thumbnails does not load.

I would like this to happend:

```
 div-thumbnail
 div-artnr
 div-dimmensions
```

Comment: can you post (fiddle) the code that you have tried so far?

Comment: Hello Mr @KaiHogan , thanks for taking an interest in helping me out. I have now updated the post with fiddle and some other jazz. My comment here should alert you on that, if I understand the site info correct.